# Is it a common cloud service feature for super admins to impersonate any other user on the service?

Tags: cloud, saas

Some argue that it is a very handy debugging feature for developers to impersonate user accounts of customers. Others argue that this feature is a bad idea for security and information protection reasons, even with approval by user being impersonated due to phishing.

Is this a common feature in cloud services? Can for instance a Microsoft "super admin" impersonate any user on Office365?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this blogpost from stackoverflow [The perils of impersonation tooling](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/07/24/the-perils-of-impersonation-tooling/) it is "pretty common" for cloud services to use impersonation tools, but evidently also very dangerous as experienced by Twitter. For production, such code is described as "radioactive" by Nick Craver (Lead architect Stackoverflow/MVP).

Microsoft uses an access control technology called Lockbox when accessing customer data in Office365. For extra security customers can enable(buy) "Customer Lockbox" where the customer must give explicit approval before Microsoft can access their data. As described in [Microsoft 365 technology controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/microsoft-365-technology-controls?view=o365-worldwide). "With both Lockbox and Customer Lockbox, all approved access is traceable to a unique user, making engineers accountable for their handling of Customer Data."